# Python - NumPy - deleting multiple rows and columns from an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Let's say I have a **square matrix** as ***input***:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I want to **count the nonzeros** in the array after removal of rows 2 and 3 and cols 2 and 3. Afterwards I want to do the same for rows 3 and 4 and cols 3 and 4. Hence the ***output*** should be:

```
0  # when removing rows/cols 2 and 3
3  # when removing rows/cols 3 and 4
```

Here is the **naive solution** using `np.delete`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0]])
np.count_nonzero(np.delete(np.delete(a, (1,2), axis=0), (1,2), axis=1))
np.count_nonzero(np.delete(np.delete(a, (2,3), axis=0), (2,3), axis=1))
```

But `np.delete` returns a new array. Is there a faster method, which involves deleting rows and columns simultaneously? Can masking be used? The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) on `np.delete` reads:

> Often it is preferable to use a boolean mask.

How do I go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: When you give these kind of questions, it's important to explain the sizes of each variable (eg. size of the matrix, number of deleted rows, etc.) because the quality a lot of answers depends on this.

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks! I know. I will try not to forget in the future. In this case the number of rows in the square matrix was never greater than 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of deleting the columns and rows you don't want, it is easier to select the ones you do want. Also note that it is standard to start counting rows and columns from zeros. To get your first example, you thus want to select all elements in rows 0 and 3 and in rows 0 and 3. This requires [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), for which you can use the [ix_ utility function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_):

```
In [25]: np.count_nonzero(a[np.ix_([0,3], [0,3])])  
Out[25]: 0
```

For your second example, you want to select rows 0 and 1 and columns 0 and 1, which can be done using [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing):

```
In [26]: np.count_nonzero(a[:2,:2])
Out[26]: 3
```

Comment: `numpy.ix` was exactly what I was after. I should sit down and read the numpy documentation one day. Thanks!

Comment: Reading through whole manuals just to discover obscure but useful functions is not a lot of fun. Better work your way through some basic tutorials, and some more detailed ones about import but confusing concepts like broadcasting and the one about indexing I linked in my answer.

Comment: The first still involves copying. Note that if you only ever delete 2 rows and columns yet have a large matrix, one could take the sums of the 9 sub-matrices between the deleted lines. Those slices would not involve copies.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to modify your original array by deleting rows/columns, in order to count the number of non zero elements. Simply use indexing,

```
a = np.array([[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0]])
irows, icols = np.indices(a.shape)
mask = (irows!=2)&(irows!=3)&(icols!=2)&(icols!=3)
np.count_nonzero(a[mask])
```

Comment: This is also a good solution, but writing down an explicit mask for each case is not an option. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Well you could easily extend this, defining function that takes in the rows/columns numbers and outputs a corresponding mask. Although I agree that if you can live with selecting the remaining columns with `np.ix_` that would be a better approach.